# After map.data.loadGeoJson, events of circle is covered by polygons of Geo Json

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

After I load Geo Json file by map.data.loadGeoJson(), makers and circles are covered by polygons and their event cannot be clicked.
Here is sample codes. How should I do? and is there any other way to disable "clickable" of these polygons? Thank you.

```
map.data.loadGeoJson(samplejson.json);
 // Add circle overlay and bind to marker
                var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                    map: map,
                    radius: 1600, // 10 miles in metres
                    fillColor: fill_color_val,
                    strokeColor: '#F5F5F5',
                    strokeWeight: 2,
                    fillOpacity: 1,
                });

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latlng,
                    title: data[i].Author,
                    draggable: false,
                    map: map
                });
                marker.setVisible(false);

                circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');

                var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: "<div>Hello! World</div>",
                    maxWidth: 500
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(circle, 'click', getInfoCallback(latlng, 14));
```

Comment: can you confirm that at least the marker is still clickable? The other overlays  could be brought on top of google.maps.Data layer by modifying their zIndex property.

Comment: all markers and circles can't be clickable after loadGeoJson(). 
how can I set zIndex of data layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use zindex to other layers not to cover by map.data